# Ads on android backend of PlayN

Tags: android, playn

I have been trying to get working admob in android, but the app keep crashing at start whenever I add the adView for the ad.

Answer (score 2):

Ok so I finally got the ads working on our android version of our game with PlayN,the procedure is a little long so I wrote a [blog post](http://foobraco.nodejitsu.com/working-ads-in-android-backend-of-playn) about it so you can check it out, let me know if you have any questions.